# Is Africa the only continent where chattel slavery still exists?

Tags: africa, slavery

The only two places on earth I can find that still have chattel slavery are Sudan and Mauritania. I have read reports that it still occurs in the Sahel region in general but I can't find any concrete evidence of it in other specific countries.  Regardless of how abhorrent I am not asking about bonded labor, forced labor, forced marriage, discrimination, sex trade, or religious/ritual servitude.

Comment: "Openly tolerated" opens the door to a lot of places, including India.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After 2014, that is no longer the case (see @indigochild's answer for pre-2014 status); because [ISIS practices what amounts to chattel slavery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_21st-century_Islamism#By_ISIS), on the continent of Asia. They buy and sell slaves and the slaves are considered property, which fits the chattel slavery definition.

Comment: From a pamphlet from a pro-ISIS Twitter account: "It is permissible to buy, sell, or give as a gift female captives and slaves, for they are merely property, which can be disposed of [as long as that doesn't cause [the Muslim ummah] any harm or damage." Which corresponds with the testimony of survivors. Chattel slavery indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Proving a negative is impossible, but I don't think you will find chattel slavery anywhere else.

A single counter-example would prove that chattel slavery still exists somewhere outside of Africa.  However, after reading through the publications of several anti-slavery organizations I could only find the two examples you mentioned (Sudan and Mauritania).

Many organizations reported that these were the only places that chattel slavery is common. As an example, here is something from Brandeis University's [sexual ethics project](https://www.brandeis.edu/projects/fse/slavery/contemporary/essay-chattel-slavery.html):

> Traditional slavery, often called chattel slavery, is probably the least prevalent of the contemporary forms of slavery.  According to the American Anti-Slavery Group, in Mauritania—where slavery was legally abolished in 1980—90,000 darker-skinned Africans still live as the property of the Muslim Berber communities.

The original source from the American Anti-Slavery Group was unavailable (link broken).  The Berber are an ethnic group living in northern Africa, which lends some (non-conclusive) credibility to the idea that chattel slavery is practiced there, and perhaps no where else.

Answer (score -4):

I don't believe so, from what I've read chattel slavery still happens in some parts of Uganda, Zambia and the DRC. Hope this helps.

Comment: All three of those places are in Africa, but your conclusion is that there are other places besides Africa.